# How to replace all Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, h2

Right now I have the following table structure:

```
USER
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL
    USER_DATA_ID BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES USER_DATA(ID)

USER_DATA
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL
    PERSON_DATA_ID BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES PERSON_DATA(ID)

PERSON_DATA
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL
```

So as you can see all person data ids are in the `USER_DATA` table. I now have to make a huge change. The person data ids should now be referenced inside the `USER` table without losing the data. So the new schema must be:

```
USER
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL
    USER_DATA_ID BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES USER_DATA(ID)
    PERSON_DATA_ID BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES PERSON_DATA(ID)
```

Can I do it with simple SQL statements? Im working with H2 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First delete the `foreign key` that references `USER_DATA(PERSON_DATA_ID)`
   to `PERSON_DATA(ID)`.
2. Add a new column on `USER` table `PERSON_DATA_ID`.
3. Copy the column `PERSON_DATA_ID` to `USER`:
   `INSERT INTO USER(PERSON_DATA_ID) SELECT ud.PERSON_DATA_ID FROM USER_DATA AS ud INNER JOIN USER AS u ON ud.ID = u.USER_DATA_ID`
4. Delete the `USER_DATA(PERSON_DATA_ID)` column.
5. Set up a new `foreign key` relationship between `USER` and `PERSON_DATA`